# Getting vertex list from python-igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I have been scouring the docs trying to find a function that will return a list vertices from an iGraph graph but can't find one. Does anyone know how to do get a list of vertices from an iGraph graph?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [property](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#vs) `vs` of the `igraph.Graph` object refers to its [`VertexSeq`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.VertexSeq-class.html) object:

```
g = Graph.Full(3)
vseq = g.vs
print type(vseq)
# <class 'igraph.VertexSeq'>
```

You can also create  one from your graph:

```
g = Graph.Full(3)
vs = VertexSeq(g)
```

You can use the [property](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#vs) as an iterator:

```
g = Graph.Full(3)
for v in g.vs:
    # do stuff with v (which is an individual vertex)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also try a much simpler version of the command in python by

`G = igraph.Graph.Read("your_inputgraph.txt", format="edgelist", directed=False)` # for reading the graph to igraph

```
nodes = G.vs.indices
```

nodes will be the list of all nodes in igraph.

Comment: This is quite fast and lists all ids with just one line. Great!

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for **names** (in case you used names for your vertices), the following code will give you the list of names of all vertices in sequence:

```
named_vertex_list = g.vs()["name"]
```

If you are looking for just the **indices**, then simply creating a range object with vcount will give you the indices

```
vertex_indices = range(g.vcount())
```